# convert string to bigint , this is really a string, is that possible?

Tags: c#, database

I would like to convert a true string to store in database after it,
this is the example of data that I am using

"TaskCode21"
is that possible I convert this to "biginteger" and store it in database, because the datatype of this field is created in bigint  in database ?

Comment: Well what value would you want? Just "21"? Will the prefix always be "TaskCode"? There isn't currently enough context to give you a good answer.

Comment: Yeah. Especially because most scenarios make no sense if the field is only a biginteger. THe context must be quite some - SNAFU.

Comment: Is there a justification why you don't want to store string as string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is change the field type to string

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "TaskCode21";

str.ToUpper().Replace("TaskCode","");

  int number =0;

int.tryParse(str.Trim(),number); //number is the variable that would store the integer extracted           from the string
```